# float function not properly working because divs are different sizes

Tags: html, css, alignment

Hello and thanks in advance, please keep in mind I'm a beginner at this :)

I wanted to practice positioning div's so I made a sort of grid of books that I read. Each div consists of a writer and his book(s).

It looks like this now:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNZZF.png

I used float:left; for all the divs, so they are sorted alphabetically from left to right until the full width is used, and then from top to bottom. 
I used height, width: auto; , which causes 'Camus' div to be bigger because it lists three books. 
Problem is, because Camus' height is bigger, the div in the row under the div is not positioned to the left of the page, but to the side of Camus. As you can see I increased the margins but that didn't solve the problem. How should I fix this so that every row is like the first or last one?

Thanks

Comment: please add your code (HTML/CSS) to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be to put each container inside another container and `float:left;` the parent container and also give it a defined height. then the styling used on the current containers will still be used to make them look exactly like they do now, except that they will align properly.

Example

```
CSS
.parent-container {
    float:left;
    height:200px /*or whatever height looks best for you*/
}
.current-container {
    /*current style you are already using here*/
}

HTML
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="current-container">
        /* all the same content you already have*/
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is impossible with `float: left` if the containers aren't exactly the same height.
Give all divs the same height and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ . If that's not quite what you're looking for, you might not be able to do it with just css. Here's a javascript solution: http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/

Answer (score 0):

When you float a node, you remove it from the document's flow. So different height nodes will tend to "wrap" around in a non-linear manner like that. I think there are really only two ways to do this... either figure out a way to wrap things or make them the same height.